# How to offset ImageWindow's "zoom to" or "panTo" position on opening?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have modified the standard info window to include self-defined tab-bar at the top.

Hence the auto-panning isn't working correctly, as there is a part of the `InfoWindow` that isn't recognized as such resulting in this flawed output:

[image: How it's rendered.]

Now I want to offset the panTo-position that gets calculated by `infoWindow.open()` for ~30px on the y-axis, yet I do not know if it's possible, and if so, how.

[image: How it should be rendered]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to move the infowindow up (or down?) by 30px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no offset directly related to the area used by the [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) when calling `open()` method. You should set `disableAutoPan` to `true` on [infoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) object and use `panTo()` map's method with an offset on the `LatLng` object passed.

Comment: I did as you told, just instead of `panTo` I used `panBy(0, infoWindowCombinedHeight)`.